# Light distribution measurements- Isolux curve for automotive lighting

Tags: lighting

Can we get the isolux or isocandela plots in Blender?
I have an automotive lamp sending light in x-direction and the light is projected over a plane 3m away. Is there any chance we can get the light distribution of light projected on the plane, preferably in lux or candela?
If not, do you know any free software which does the same?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Blender supports IES files

Some examples you can grab here: https://ieslibrary.com/en/browse

The Illuminating Engineering Society (IES) has defined a file format which describes a light's distribution from a light source using real world measured data. These IES Photometric files, or IES Profiles, are a lighting industry standard method of diagramming the brightness and falloff of light as it exists a particular real world light fixture. It enables them to account for reflective surfaces in the light fixture, the shape of the light bulb, and any lensing effects that happens. This type of photometric lighting is primarily used in Enterprise fields such as Media and Entertainment or Architecture and Manufacturing.

You can use IES textures in Cycles in node editor. Enable Nodes for point lamp and plug in IES texture into emission node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
In my case, I use the IES files for light rays of lamps and these lights undergo refraction, reflection and TIR and emerge as the output light. But I am confused how to get the  light distribution of this output light, projected on to a plane.

Comment: Ah, now I've got your question... I see. Blender is not designed for measurement. You should get the correct results if you set up a plane at the distance, though, but you can't export them into specific format. If you are asking about software recommendation,  it is out-of-topic here.

Comment: oh! is it! Thank you so much for the response.